# Target data within <div> tag with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a `<div>` that has less height and the data-image-src be grayscale until it is clicked, upon which it will restore full height and color.

The way I have my parallax jquery set up, the background image is set in the data-image-src and am not sure how to target it with CSS to make sure it is getting the `filter: grayscale(100%)`.

Here is how the HTMl is set up

`<div class="parallaxmenu" id="parallax-4" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="../pictures/drinks.png">`

And I'm trying to target the `data-image-src="(Image)"`

Is there a way to do this or will I have to set up my Jquery differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `div[data-image-src]` to target any div with that attribute or use `div[data-image-src="(Image)"]` to target a div with that attribute and that attribute value.

Comment: This worked to target the div itself. Unfortunately, I am trying to target the data-image-src itself. I was wondering if there was any way to specifically give the image in the data-image-src a grayscale

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to target, @zgood answered this question, but if you want **to get the value** of the attribute, you need to use Javascript:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("parallax-4").getAttribute("data-image-src");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div class="parallaxmenu" id="parallax-4" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="../pictures/drinks.png">
```

Comment: You can target elments in CSS by attributes see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Comment: @zgood, yes, you can target, but can you get the value of the attribute via only CSS?

Comment: No you can't get a value in css, css is just for styling, but that was not his question.... _And I'm trying to target the data-image-src="(Image)" Is there a way to do this_. He is trying to target it for styling purposes not get the value

Comment: np, but just an fyi... you can actually retrieve a value from in attribute and set it as `content` in CSS. i.e. `content: attr(title);`. But I don't think it has great support. See [here](https://davidwalsh.name/css-content-attr)

Comment: @zgood, but what's the reason to get this value via CSS? can we do anything helpful with it via CSS and without Javascript?

Comment: ya its not too helpful you're right.  right now the `attr()` css function can only be used for the `content` property so its only good for setting text content of an element. So if you had `<a href="#" title="My Link"></a>` you could in CSS make a style like this: `a { content: attr(title); }` and the link would render in the browser like this: `<a href="#" title="My Link">My Link</a>`. Again, not very useful, but possible.

Comment: @zgood, good explanation, now I will know about such a possibility